# iteratively traverse n amount of nested maps and lists

Tags: java, maps

I have a generic map that can contain a list of maps which can iteratively contain another list of maps or another map of object etc.

Map mymap;

I need a way without knowing the structure of the map to update a nested value. For example say my map looks like this:

```
{mymap : myList[{'myObject' : 'someValue'}, {'myObject' : 'someOtherValue'}]}
```

Based on some sort of path expression such as 'mymap.myList.myObject' I need to be able to replace all 'myObject values with a new value.

How can I iteratively traverse all the maps and lists to get to the values I want? This needs to be generic so that the structure of the map can change and I iterate based on a path expression.

Comment: You want to replace the keys in a map with new objects?   Or with _a_ new object?

Comment: i want to replace the value of a certain key with a new value.

Comment: so based on the above example i want to replace all occurrences of 'myObject' with a new value.

Answer (score 1):

[JsonPath](https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath) might be a fit. Make sure you have these two dependencies on your class path:

```
com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:2.2.0
com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.7.0
```

And then:

```
import java.util.*;
import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath;

public class Sandbox {

    private static class Widget {
        private final String id;

        public Widget(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Widget{id='" + id + "'}";
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map map1 = new HashMap();
        map1.put("myObject", new Widget("cog"));

        Map map2 = new HashMap();
        map2.put("myObject", new Widget("sprog"));

        Map root = new HashMap();
        root.put("myList", new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(map1, map2)));
        root.put("myObject", new Widget("frobulator"));

        System.out.println("BEFORE: " + root);

        // set the value of all 'myObject' nodes no matter how deeply nested
        JsonPath.parse(root).set("$..myObject", new Widget("novaDetonator"));

        System.out.println("AFTER:" + root);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
BEFORE: {myList=[{myObject=Widget{id='cog'}}, {myObject=Widget{id='sprog'}}], myObject=Widget{id='frobulator'}}
2016-05-16 13:44:44,337 [main] DEBUG  com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.path.CompiledPath - Evaluating path: $..['myObject']
2016-05-16 13:44:44,343 [main] DEBUG  com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.JsonContext - Set path $['myObject'] new value Widget{id='novaDetonator'}
2016-05-16 13:44:44,344 [main] DEBUG  com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.JsonContext - Set path $['myList'][0]['myObject'] new value Widget{id='novaDetonator'}
2016-05-16 13:44:44,344 [main] DEBUG  com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.JsonContext - Set path $['myList'][1]['myObject'] new value Widget{id='novaDetonator'}
AFTER:{myList=[{myObject=Widget{id='novaDetonator'}}, {myObject=Widget{id='novaDetonator'}}], myObject=Widget{id='novaDetonator'}}
```

Of course your replacement value could be a `String` instead of a `Widget`; it's neat that JsonPath can work with either.